# Qt widget promotion: whats difference btw these two codes?

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to reimplement `mouseClickEvent` since I need to distinguish right click and left click. I promoted my `QListView` to `WavList`, and wrote the following code, but error occurred.

**wavlist.h**

```
#ifndef WAVLIST_H
#define WAVLIST_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QListView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class WavList : public QListView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WavList(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
};

#endif // WAVLIST_H
```

**wavlist.cpp**

```
#include "wavlist.h"

WavList::WavList(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "lol";
}

void WavList::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
    else
    {
        QListView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I got the following error:
`C2614: 'WavList': illegal member initialization: 'QWidget' is not a base or member`.

So I fixed my code like this.

```
WavList::WavList(QWidget *parent)
{
    this->setParent(parent);
    qDebug() << "lol";
}
```

And this worked! My question is, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error should be clear: `QWidget` is not a parent of `WavList`, `QListView` is. You can only have direct parents in the constructor initializer lists:

```
WavList::WavList(QWidget *parent) : QListView(parent)
{
   ...
}
```

The other constructor doesn't use a constructor initializer list to set the widget relationship, but uses a specific function. The end result might be the same, but the semantics are very different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!